OKHTTP DNS Cache
I am testing my connection on super low network and I have noticed DNS is also taking sometime to resolve. I am using OKhttp to open connection (websocket), is there any way to enable DNS Caching for okhttp request?
I want to increase the default TTL for DNS cache if there is any by default.

Provide custom implementation of interface Dns and cache the result of the lookup.
eg. there's also okhttp-dnsoverhttps, which shows how this would have too look alike.
